# jquery append content after erasing previous content

Tags: jquery, json, append, preventdefault

I thought that using .append function previous finding specifyc content in a .json file it will returns only one time content if i put .empty property of a div before .append once again. BUT I'M WRONG.

I think there must be a function stopping these cycle but I dont get it.

```
    $('#mn_1').live('click', function() {
        $('#tt_mn').text("");
        var idx = $(this).data('articleidx');
        $.getJSON("auth/data_prod.json", function(data) {
            $("<p class='prod_c'>" + data.articles[idx].title + "</p>").appendTo("#tt_mn");
        });
    });
```

at document.ready

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#tt_mn').text("");
});
```

thank you very much.

Comment: Please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) illustrating the problem. (Store your JSON to a variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `html()` in the callback it will replace the previous data with the new one you have provided

```
$("#tt_mn").html($("<p class='prod_c'>" + data.articles[idx].title + "</p>"));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NH9Un/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understand the question, but is the problem emptying the div before appending?

I'll give it a shot anyways

```
$(document).on('click', '#mn_1', function() {
    var idx = $(this).data('articleidx');
    $.getJSON("auth/data_prod.json", function(data) {
        $("#tt_mn").html("<p class='prod_c'>" + data.articles[idx].title + "</p>");
    });
});
```